# How to revive pantheon files? Hung, reinstalled, unresponsive

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-files

I would like to resurrect Pantheon Files. It has crapped out in some manner I can't easily understand of deal with, and I don't know how to proceed.

Was dragging files between Files tabs when it hung. Got one bonus relaunch and most files reappeared with green dots. Further attempts to launch showed only a hung interface, frozen at the same mid-draw point with spinners in both tabs, and I had to kill it to quit it. I have no idea what the green dots represent and found nothing online explaining colour codes.

Command line full purge and AppCentre reinstall achieved, but now Files is *extremely* slow to launch and items are still green dotted. Today I noticed some blank and one orange dot; icon associations seem fine. It really feels like it's still trying to figure something out, then presents a failed best guess.

I have continued to use an alternative file manager without issue and the file system seems okay.

I thought apt purge got rid of everything related to an application but it appears something is mangled and cached. I tried apt remove first but had the same outcome. Also, I didn't find any other pantheon processes to kill, except the daemon I assume I just reinstalled.

Comment: Not too sure what is causing your problem but the green dots indicate the status of files in a Git repository.  If you are having problems with certain tabs being restored on startup then one fix is to change the "restore-tabs" setting to false in `io/elementary/files/preferences` using dconf-editor app or with the commandline ` gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences restore-tabs false`.  Can you recall what the url of the problem tabs was? Were they remote?

Comment: Also, could you confirm which version of Files you are using on which version of elementaryos?

Comment: Reinstalling Files will not overwrite an existing user settings file so if there is something about the urls you are trying to restore that Files cannot cope with, then the reinstalled Files will also try to restore them and freeze.

Comment: You are right that there should be documentation of the Git status emblems somewhere (or tooltips).  Maybe a File wiki page.

Comment: Sorry, thought Hera was self-explanatory: Hera v5.1.7 Files v4.5.0,  although I'm struggling to prove the Files version. AppCentre says v4.5.0 but pantheon-files shows command unavailable in the shell. How to view rev? 


Excellent advice on the restore-tabs toggle but not quite; it reduced the tabs to a single default but it's still hung up on filling in that tab.

Comment: No URL input at the time, but if you're referring to the basics that Files uses to address things I thought I was dealing with a couple of locations inside my home directory, selected from the side bar.

About reinstalling, I thought "purge" was there exactly to toss everything because "remove" ignored the scope of the user profile. So is purge not really a purge?

Comment: And Git. Yeah, I'm betting this is related beyond just some dots. How much you wanna bet it hates the whole repo because I unwittingly spanned the border, or maybe copied react files by mistake? So legitimately, does anything with a green dot need a pull? Maybe it'll look after itself if I waste everything that looks like react or git logs. Either way, I'm not sure that explains the Files hang, but I can now browse my single tab so does that mean my problem is solved? Did 1 tab free up enough resources that Files will should play nice from now on? About 30s to draw that tab, but it works.

Comment: Sorry - I missed the "Hera" badge against your issue.  Do mean `sudo apt show pantheon-files` does not find pantheon-files? But Files still runs? That is strange. Have you ever installed it manually from source? Are there any pantheon-files related files beneath the folder `/usr/local` especially in `/usr/local/bin`? If so they will run in preference to anything installed from AppCenter. You should manually delete any Files related files beneath `\usr\local`

Comment: The git emblems are being redesigned at the moment so should be a little more self-evident.

Comment: When tabs are not restored then the Home folder is displayed on startup.  If this is taking 30 seconds to load on a reasonably modern computer then something else is abnormal. You could try using `gnome-system-monitor` or `htop` to see whether Files itself is doing a lot of processing or if it is waiting for some other process.

Comment: Does your Home directory contain the root folder of a really huge git repository by any chance?

Comment: Yes, "show", and confirms v4.5.0, It never occurred to me that a graphic application in Linux wouldn't have a command outside of APT, but I plead ignorance.

Comment: I was using a system monitor, to check and kill. I repeated to make sure for you, and it hovers around 30% for about 30s, drops to zero once the tab finishes rendering.

Comment: Good to see anything that makes git more understandable. My Git relationship, though, is pure chaos. It feels like my Files is now working properly or doing its best, just overwhelmed. I haven't used Git for about three years and it would be non-trivial to get back into things. I plan to soon, so I can address my home directory then as it's trash, and create a new repo from scratch. Would you like to put up your restore-tabs setting as an answer, and I can sign off on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files is known to struggle with showing very large folders (with >10,000 items) in IconView.  Large, deep, git repositories are even worse since Files tries to determine the status of each subfolder based on all its children. If the folder is remote or on a slow device then it is even worse. Showing large folders in List View is much faster but the git problem remains.

If Files is closed with a tab showing such a folder then startup will be delayed as it tries to restore it.  You can turn off restoring by turning of "History" in System Settings/Security & Privacy (but that affects several apps) or with the commandline  `gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences restore-tabs false` or using dconf-editor.

Comment: Well said, thank you for your advice.